# UITableViewCell gaves default blue highlight after second-third selection for .gray on macOS using Catalyst

Tags: ios, macos, mac-catalyst

I trying to port my `iOS` app to `macOS` using `Catalyst`, but no matter what the `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.gray` style visually show the `.blue` highlight, while the `.style` value still prints `.gray`.
I tried to force reset it in the following functions but with no luck.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?
```

No matter what, it goes back `.blue` from `.gray`. If its `.none`, it stays `.none`.

Possible workaround was to set a background color manually, which feels like not right.

Comment: Have you ever managed to work around this?

Comment: @cdf1982 I made a `UITableViewCell` subclass and made my own selection logic ... than I washed my hands.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, now my hands are dirty too ;) But it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

The blue color was from the focused state, so you will need to override the `canBecomeFocused` property in your UITableViewCell subclass

```
override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default way of setting the selection style on Mac Catalyst did not work for me:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .gray
```

On the Mac Catalyst app the selection showed first gray then on the next click blue. To work around it I applied @Laszlo's solution. However you don't need a custom UITableViewCell. You can create a custom background view and set the `.selectedBackgroundView` property of the `UITableViewCell` instance to a custom background view.

```
let customSelectionBackgroundView = UIView()
customSelectionBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
cell.selectedBackgroundView = customSelectionBackgroundView
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, the blue highlight comes from the focused state. To disable it you can implement the table view function `canFocusRowAt` and just return `false`, like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked so far. Thanks a lot for your answer.